# Go app file/package structure

Tags: go

I'm building a CLI app that imports some data (e.g. from a db or CSV, XML) and exports it to some other format (e.g. to a db or file). An importer and exporter is specified when the app is started as input parameters to the app.
I'm looking for some inspiration on how to structure the files/packages.

At the moment, I have separated each importer and exporter in its own file. Each importer satisfies a general importer interface:

```
type Importer interface {
    Import() ([]*data, error)
    PreProcess() error
    PostProcess() error
}
```

So, for instance, `CSVImporter` would implement these 3 functions. Likewise for the exporters. Currently all importers and exporters are part of the main package together with the main file. I think this makes the most sense, as they are part of the app, and should not be used in other projects. Also, since I have a lot of config settings (some general and some for each importer and exporter), that are unmarshalled in the beginning of my main package, I believe my importers and exporters should be part of the same package, in order for me to use the settings there.

```
package main

type ConfigFile struct {
    Environment    string
    Resources      *Resources
    Importers      *Importers
    Exporters      *Exporters
    ...
}

func main() {
    cfg ConfigFile


    // Load config file settings
    err := viper.Unmarshal(&cfg)

    var i StockImporter
    var e StockExporter

    // Create selected importer.
    switch viper.GetString("importer") {
         case "csv-importer":
         i = NewCSVImporter()
         ...
    }
}
```

My current file structure looks like the following:

```
app
|- main.go
|- importer.go
|- csvimporter.go
|- xmlimporter.go
|- exporter.go
|- csvexporter.go
| - lib
    | - db.go
```

I hope my current structure is described clearly. My question is: Are there better ways to structure my app? Specifically, I dont like having all the files in the same dir as main. Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)

From the documentation, this is how a workspace should look in practice:

```
bin/
    hello                          # command executable
    outyet                         # command executable
pkg/
    linux_amd64/
        github.com/golang/example/
            stringutil.a           # package object
src/
    github.com/golang/example/
        .git/                      # Git repository metadata
    hello/
        hello.go               # command source
    outyet/
        main.go                # command source
        main_test.go           # test source
    stringutil/
        reverse.go             # package source
        reverse_test.go        # test source
    golang.org/x/image/
        .git/                      # Git repository metadata
    bmp/
        reader.go              # package source
        writer.go              # package source
    ... (many more repositories and packages omitted) ...
```

I would probably create a CSV and an XML package, and put their corresponding importers/exporters there, or have an importer and an exporter package.

### Update:

Suggested project structure -

```
app
|- main.go
|- config
    |- config.go
|- importer
    |- importer.go
    |- csv.go
    |- xml.go
|- exporter
    |- exporter.go
    |- csv.go
    |- xml.go
```

Comment: If I create an importer and exporter, how will I be able to access my config struct, that was created in main?

Comment: @Mads i would have thought only the code that initializes the structs needs access to the config, not the structs themselves

Comment: @Mads You can always inject the dependency. So instead of having `func NewCSVImporter() *CSVImporter`, you can have `func NewCSVImporter(config *ConfigFile) *CSVImporter`.

Comment: @mscheker Yes, dependecy injection must be way to go. But having defined my `ConfigFile` struct in the top of my main package, will I be able to access it `package importer`? I guess in my type `CSVimporter` struct, I'll have a member `conf *ConfigFile`, that'll get set when calling `NewCSVImporter(config *ConfigFile)`.

Comment: @Mads Do you have to define `ConfigFile` in the `main` package? It seems that you're better off having a `config` package and sharing the package across your importers and exporters.

Comment: @mscheker, no i can define a separate config package. That would do the work, afaik. But when I thought about it before, it just seemed a bit strange to have a package for just handling a config file. But maybe I haven't understood Go's concept of packages yet.

Comment: @Mads Well, here's the thing. Do you even need the `ConfigFile` struct to begin with? Couldn't you just abstract that into the corresponding importer/exporter? Just an idea.

Comment: @mscheker, What exactly do you mean by abstracting it into the importer/exporter? I wouldn't mind getting rid of the `ConfigFile` struct, but my config file itself, is fairly large, because I have some settings for each type of importer and exporter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151888/discussion-between-mscheker-and-mads).

Comment: The file structure example in the answer doesn't actually seem to have anything to do with the question (it's not a q about GOPATH structure, it's about project structure). The rest of the answer is relevant though so not going to downvote for that.

Comment: @Adrian Updated my answer to reflect the suggested project structure discussed with OP.